# Convert SQL Query result into array of strings

Tags: java, sqlite

I am making queries to a SQLite3 database in Java using the SQLiteJDBC (Java JDBC driver for SQLite).

*If I make the SQL query **SELECT name, pass FROM loginTable WHERE name='%s';** is there a function to Return OR Convert the name & pass strings returned from the query into a String array or ArrayList?*

The following code attempts to put the queries return into an array list but it fails, I know that the SQL database is fine & the query I make because when I do this in command line it works.

```
ArrayList <String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery( "SELECT ..." );

for (int i=0; rs.next(); i++)
{
   result.add( rs.getString(i) );
}
```

It fails because the table loginTable has the columns: Index, name, pass. So looking at above, when i=0, & I go rs.getString(0), it tries to get the string in the Index column.

The error output is

> java.sql.SQLException: column 0 out of bounds [1,1]

**Does anyone know how I can put all results from an SQL query(ResultSet object) in an ArrayList or array?**

Answer (score 11):

In JDBC, the columns are indexed starting from 1, not 0.

Comment: +1 Coming from .net `DataReader`, didn't know that the JDBC starts at 1

Comment: @The Scrum Meister same applies to praparedStatement,you never set parameter o.

Answer (score 9):

To store the first row's columns only, try

```
int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
rs.next();
for (int i = 0; i <columnCount ; i++)
{
   result.add( rs.getString(i + 1) );
}
```

If you want to store a `ArrayList<String[]>` which contains all rows and all columns:

```
ArrayList <String[]> result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery( "SELECT ..." );
int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
while(rs.next())
{
    String[] row = new String[columnCount];
    for (int i=0; i <columnCount ; i++)
    {
       row[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
    }
    result.add(row);
}
```

Updated per Shaun's answer

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me:

```
public static String[] getRooms() throws SQLException, JSONException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

    Class.forName(sqlDriver);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dtbSet, dtbUsername, dtbPassword);
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT room_name FROM "+ dtbTbl2);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next())
    {
        a.add(rs.getString(1));
    }

    return (String[]) a.toArray(new String[a.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use a `for loop` because you are getting just one different column from each row... each time you hit `rs.next()`, it goes to the next row before you are done getting all the column values from one row. Instead, use `while (rs.next())` to check for the row existence.

Second, as @shaun mentioned, JDBC columns begin with 1, not zero.

Third, to put the data into a list, you will need a have a POJO, or a bean to hold all the information from each row.

So, in the end, the code comes like to be something like this:-

```
Connection con = ...; 
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT name, pass FROM loginTable WHERE name = ?");
ps.setString(1, "mike");

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

while(rs.next()) {
    String name = rs.getString(1);
    String pass = rs.getString(2);
    users.add(new User(name, pass));
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this framework.
http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/

Specifically you can query a database and return an arraylist of the query.  Here's an example in pseudo code:

```
ResultSetHandler h = new ArrayListHandler();
QueryRunner qr = new QueryRunner();

List<Object[]> results = (List<Object[]>)qr.query(sql, h);
```

Also here's another website that uses this:
http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=45