# How can I get a SQL result into a string on android studio?

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm getting the ID (EPC) from an RFID tag with an RFID reader and I'm trying to implement a code that checks if that ID exists on a SQL database (previously created and stored on the assets folder) and return all de database data if it does exist. Then, I want to store that data on a STRING.

I've tried some possible solutions presented here, but I think there is a serious problem with my code because the app crashes every time I scan an RFID tag.

Here is my Database code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;


import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import mobliescanner.com.grotg.hpp.mobilescanner.model.TagData;

public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME="tagDataDB.db";
    private static final int DB_VER=1;

    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
    }

//Função para pegar a tag pelo ID
    public List<TagData> getTagDataByID(String id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String[] sqlSelect={"TAG_ID","TAG_NUMBER","TAG_QUAL","TAG_LOCAL","TAG_DESCRICAO","GALERIA_AUTOR","GALERIA_AUTOR_LOCAL"};
        String tableName="TagData";

        qb.setTables((tableName));
        Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqlSelect,"ID LIKE ?",new String[]{"%"+id+"%"},null,null,null);
        List<TagData> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                TagData tagdata = new TagData();
                tagdata.setId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TAG_ID")));
                tagdata.setIdnum(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("TAG_NUMBER")));
                tagdata.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TAG_QUAL")));
                tagdata.setLocaltag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TAG_LOCAL")));
                tagdata.setDesctag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("TAG_DESCRICAO")));
                tagdata.setAutor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GALERIA_AUTOR")));
                tagdata.setAutorlocal(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("GALERIA_AUTOR_LOCAL")));

                result.add(tagdata);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return result;
}
```

Here is what I was trying to do on my MainActivity:

```
Database testdb = new Database(this);
String dataresult = String.valueOf(testdb.getTagDataByID(epctag));
```

Where "epctag" is a String which stores the tag ID got from the Reader.

Expected: return all de database data if and ID TAG exists on a DB than store the result into a STRING.

Actual results: app crashes every time I scan an RFID tag.

Comment: Please check this link. May be this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010930/convert-sql-query-result-into-array-of-strings

Comment: @SumanDash The problem is that all those codes refer to something that I already did on my "Database.java". I need to know about the Main Activity code.